Admin SDK licensing API and getting error
I am getting error: HttpError 400 when requesting https://licensing.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/sku/1010060001/user/prasanjit.swain%40zebra.com?alt=json returned "Invalid productId: Google-Apps". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid productId: Google-Apps', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'}]">
What to check and how to resolve the issue?

The reason that you are getting this error 400 code error message saying invalid product Id is because the SKU 1010060001 for Google Workspace Essentials (formerly G Suite Essentials) was used to be considered to be outside of the Google Workspace product line that's why "Google-Apps" as productId show the error message that you are viewing.
Changing the "productId" to the number "101006" should work and list correctly the users under this type of license.
More about the Google Workspace Essentials (formerly G Suite Essentials): https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F7681288%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=7681288&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a
Also there is page to troubleshoot some issue or examples of issues and what might be the problem or causes and how to fix it here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/support/enterprise_license_manager_api_common_errors
